# Check if email address is Subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to check if the domain belonging to an email address is a subdomain or not.

It must work with:

```
test@domain.com
test@domain.co.uk
test@subdomain.domain.com
test@subdomain.domain.co.uk
test@subdomain.domain.com.au
etc
```

So I don't think splitting the domain by . and checking how many parts is going to work.

It must be really fast as it will be processing a large array.

I have tried with the follow code:

```
var isSubdomain = function(email){

    var pattern = new RegExp("/^\w+(?:\.\w+)*@\w+(?:\.\w+)+$/");
    return pattern.test(email);

};
```

But this is always returning false.

Comment: I would say doing split is fine, all you need to do is check if the last one is 2 characters long.  If so and the split length is 4 it has a subdomain.  If not and the split length is 3 it has a subdomain.  Otherwise it has no subdomain.

Comment: Thanks Kieth, that works for my test case above.. But what about .me and .co domains?

Comment: You could do an extra check, I believe country codes is not a massive list.  So if the last 2 chars are a valid country code, plus the last condition should be 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this properly what we need to do is work out what are TLD (Top Level Domains).  I found a list of these from here -> https://github.com/mikewesthad/tld-data

What I then did is convert the data and place into a Set, you could use an object literal if ES6 can't be used.

I then work backwards from the url, if it's a TLD and then go back another.  Once I don't hit a TLD I'm then on the Domain, and the one's before that are then the subdomain.

Below I've made a simple function called urlInfo, with this you can use to extract the subdomain, domain, and the TLD's.

Because I've used a Set, this should run pretty fast too.  If you don't want the extra info you could maybe simplify the function to squeeze a bit more speed.

```js
const tlddata=
"aaa:aarp:abarth:abb:abbott:abbvie:abc:able:abogado:abudhabi:ac:academy:accenture"+
":accountant:accountants:aco:active:actor:ad:adac:ads:adult:ae:aeg:aero:aetna:af:"+
"afamilycompany:afl:africa:ag:agakhan:agency:ai:aig:aigo:airbus:airforce:airtel:a"+
"kdn:al:alfaromeo:alibaba:alipay:allfinanz:allstate:ally:alsace:alstom:am:america"+
"nexpress:americanfamily:amex:amfam:amica:amsterdam:an:analytics:android:anquan:a"+
"nz:ao:aol:apartments:app:apple:aq:aquarelle:ar:arab:aramco:archi:army:arpa:art:a"+
"rte:as:asda:asia:associates:at:athleta:attorney:au:auction:audi:audible:audio:au"+
"spost:author:auto:autos:avianca:aw:aws:ax:axa:az:azure:ba:baby:baidu:banamex:ban"+
"anarepublic:band:bank:bar:barcelona:barclaycard:barclays:barefoot:bargains:baseb"+
"all:basketball:bauhaus:bayern:bb:bbc:bbt:bbva:bcg:bcn:bd:be:beats:beauty:beer:be"+
"ntley:berlin:best:bestbuy:bet:bf:bg:bh:bharti:bi:bible:bid:bike:bing:bingo:bio:b"+
"iz:bj:bl:black:blackfriday:blanco:blockbuster:blog:bloomberg:blue:bm:bms:bmw:bn:"+
"bnl:bnpparibas:bo:boats:boehringer:bofa:bom:bond:boo:book:booking:boots:bosch:bo"+
"stik:boston:bot:boutique:box:bq:br:bradesco:bridgestone:broadway:broker:brother:"+
"brussels:bs:bt:budapest:bugatti:build:builders:business:buy:buzz:bv:bw:by:bz:bzh"+
":ca:cab:cafe:cal:call:calvinklein:cam:camera:camp:cancerresearch:canon:capetown:"+
"capital:capitalone:car:caravan:cards:care:career:careers:cars:cartier:casa:case:"+
"caseih:cash:casino:cat:catering:catholic:cba:cbn:cbre:cbs:cc:cd:ceb:center:ceo:c"+
"ern:cf:cfa:cfd:cg:ch:chanel:channel:chase:chat:cheap:chintai:chloe:christmas:chr"+
"ome:chrysler:church:ci:cipriani:circle:cisco:citadel:citi:citic:city:cityeats:ck"+
":cl:claims:cleaning:click:clinic:clinique:clothing:cloud:club:clubmed:cm:cn:co:c"+
"oach:codes:coffee:college:cologne:com:comcast:commbank:community:company:compare"+
":computer:comsec:condos:construction:consulting:contact:contractors:cooking:cook"+
"ingchannel:cool:coop:corsica:country:coupon:coupons:courses:cr:credit:creditcard"+
":creditunion:cricket:crown:crs:cruise:cruises:csc:cu:cuisinella:cv:cw:cx:cy:cymr"+
"u:cyou:cz:dabur:dad:dance:data:date:dating:datsun:day:dclk:dds:de:deal:dealer:de"+
"als:degree:delivery:dell:deloitte:delta:democrat:dental:dentist:desi:design:dev:"+
"dhl:diamonds:diet:digital:direct:directory:discount:discover:dish:diy:dj:dk:dm:d"+
"np:do:docs:doctor:dodge:dog:doha:domains:doosan:dot:download:drive:dtv:dubai:duc"+
"k:dunlop:duns:dupont:durban:dvag:dvr:dz:earth:eat:ec:eco:edeka:edu:education:ee:"+
"eg:eh:email:emerck:energy:engineer:engineering:enterprises:epost:epson:equipment"+
":er:ericsson:erni:es:esq:estate:esurance:et:etisalat:eu:eurovision:eus:events:ev"+
"erbank:exchange:expert:exposed:express:extraspace:fage:fail:fairwinds:faith:fami"+
"ly:fan:fans:farm:farmers:fashion:fast:fedex:feedback:ferrari:ferrero:fi:fiat:fid"+
"elity:fido:film:final:finance:financial:fire:firestone:firmdale:fish:fishing:fit"+
":fitness:fj:fk:flickr:flights:flir:florist:flowers:flsmidth:fly:fm:fo:foo:food:f"+
"oodnetwork:football:ford:forex:forsale:forum:foundation:fox:fr:free:fresenius:fr"+
"l:frogans:frontdoor:frontier:ftr:fujitsu:fujixerox:fun:fund:furniture:futbol:fyi"+
":ga:gal:gallery:gallo:gallup:game:games:gap:garden:gb:gbiz:gd:gdn:ge:gea:gent:ge"+
"nting:george:gf:gg:ggee:gh:gi:gift:gifts:gives:giving:gl:glade:glass:gle:global:"+
"globo:gm:gmail:gmbh:gmo:gmx:gn:godaddy:gold:goldpoint:golf:goo:goodhands:goodyea"+
"r:goog:google:gop:got:gov:gp:gq:gr:grainger:graphics:gratis:green:gripe:grocery:"+
"group:gs:gt:gu:guardian:gucci:guge:guide:guitars:guru:gw:gy:hair:hamburg:hangout"+
":haus:hbo:hdfc:hdfcbank:health:healthcare:help:helsinki:here:hermes:hgtv:hiphop:"+
"hisamitsu:hitachi:hiv:hk:hkt:hm:hn:hockey:holdings:holiday:homedepot:homegoods:h"+
"omes:homesense:honda:honeywell:horse:hospital:host:hosting:hot:hoteles:hotels:ho"+
"tmail:house:how:hr:hsbc:ht:htc:hu:hughes:hyatt:hyundai:ibm:icbc:ice:icu:id:ie:ie"+
"ee:ifm:iinet:ikano:il:im:imamat:imdb:immo:immobilien:in:industries:infiniti:info"+
":ing:ink:institute:insurance:insure:int:intel:international:intuit:investments:i"+
"o:ipiranga:iq:ir:irish:is:iselect:ismaili:ist:istanbul:it:itau:itv:iveco:iwc:jag"+
"uar:java:jcb:jcp:je:jeep:jetzt:jewelry:jio:jlc:jll:jm:jmp:jnj:jo:jobs:joburg:jot"+
":joy:jp:jpmorgan:jprs:juegos:juniper:kaufen:kddi:ke:kerryhotels:kerrylogistics:k"+
"erryproperties:kfh:kg:kh:ki:kia:kim:kinder:kindle:kitchen:kiwi:km:kn:koeln:komat"+
"su:kosher:kp:kpmg:kpn:kr:krd:kred:kuokgroup:kw:ky:kyoto:kz:la:lacaixa:ladbrokes:"+
"lamborghini:lamer:lancaster:lancia:lancome:land:landrover:lanxess:lasalle:lat:la"+
"tino:latrobe:law:lawyer:lb:lc:lds:lease:leclerc:lefrak:legal:lego:lexus:lgbt:li:"+
"liaison:lidl:life:lifeinsurance:lifestyle:lighting:like:lilly:limited:limo:linco"+
"ln:linde:link:lipsy:live:living:lixil:lk:loan:loans:locker:locus:loft:lol:london"+
":lotte:lotto:love:lpl:lplfinancial:lr:ls:lt:ltd:ltda:lu:lundbeck:lupin:luxe:luxu"+
"ry:lv:ly:ma:macys:madrid:maif:maison:makeup:man:management:mango:map:market:mark"+
"eting:markets:marriott:marshalls:maserati:mattel:mba:mc:mcd:mcdonalds:mckinsey:m"+
"d:me:med:media:meet:melbourne:meme:memorial:men:menu:meo:merckmsd:metlife:mf:mg:"+
"mh:miami:microsoft:mil:mini:mint:mit:mitsubishi:mk:ml:mlb:mls:mm:mma:mn:mo:mobi:"+
"mobile:mobily:moda:moe:moi:mom:monash:money:monster:montblanc:mopar:mormon:mortg"+
"age:moscow:moto:motorcycles:mov:movie:movistar:mp:mq:mr:ms:msd:mt:mtn:mtpc:mtr:m"+
"u:museum:mutual:mutuelle:mv:mw:mx:my:mz:na:nab:nadex:nagoya:name:nationwide:natu"+
"ra:navy:nba:nc:ne:nec:net:netbank:netflix:network:neustar:new:newholland:news:ne"+
"xt:nextdirect:nexus:nf:nfl:ng:ngo:nhk:ni:nico:nike:nikon:ninja:nissan:nissay:nl:"+
"no:nokia:northwesternmutual:norton:now:nowruz:nowtv:np:nr:nra:nrw:ntt:nu:nyc:nz:"+
"obi:observer:off:office:okinawa:olayan:olayangroup:oldnavy:ollo:om:omega:one:ong"+
":onl:online:onyourside:ooo:open:oracle:orange:org:organic:orientexpress:origins:"+
"osaka:otsuka:ott:ovh:pa:page:pamperedchef:panasonic:panerai:paris:pars:partners:"+
"parts:party:passagens:pay:pccw:pe:pet:pf:pfizer:pg:ph:pharmacy:phd:philips:phone"+
":photo:photography:photos:physio:piaget:pics:pictet:pictures:pid:pin:ping:pink:p"+
"ioneer:pizza:pk:pl:place:play:playstation:plumbing:plus:pm:pn:pnc:pohl:poker:pol"+
"itie:porn:post:pr:pramerica:praxi:press:prime:pro:prod:productions:prof:progress"+
"ive:promo:properties:property:protection:pru:prudential:ps:pt:pub:pw:pwc:py:qa:q"+
"pon:quebec:quest:qvc:racing:radio:raid:re:read:realestate:realtor:realty:recipes"+
":red:redstone:redumbrella:rehab:reise:reisen:reit:reliance:ren:rent:rentals:repa"+
"ir:report:republican:rest:restaurant:review:reviews:rexroth:rich:richardli:ricoh"+
":rightathome:ril:rio:rip:rmit:ro:rocher:rocks:rodeo:rogers:room:rs:rsvp:ru:rugby"+
":ruhr:run:rw:rwe:ryukyu:sa:saarland:safe:safety:sakura:sale:salon:samsclub:samsu"+
"ng:sandvik:sandvikcoromant:sanofi:sap:sapo:sarl:sas:save:saxo:sb:sbi:sbs:sc:sca:"+
"scb:schaeffler:schmidt:scholarships:school:schule:schwarz:science:scjohnson:scor"+
":scot:sd:se:search:seat:secure:security:seek:select:sener:services:ses:seven:sew"+
":sex:sexy:sfr:sg:sh:shangrila:sharp:shaw:shell:shia:shiksha:shoes:shop:shopping:"+
"shouji:show:showtime:shriram:si:silk:sina:singles:site:sj:sk:ski:skin:sky:skype:"+
"sl:sling:sm:smart:smile:sn:sncf:so:soccer:social:softbank:software:sohu:solar:so"+
"lutions:song:sony:soy:space:spiegel:spot:spreadbetting:sr:srl:srt:ss:st:stada:st"+
"aples:star:starhub:statebank:statefarm:statoil:stc:stcgroup:stockholm:storage:st"+
"ore:stream:studio:study:style:su:sucks:supplies:supply:support:surf:surgery:suzu"+
"ki:sv:swatch:swiftcover:swiss:sx:sy:sydney:symantec:systems:sz:tab:taipei:talk:t"+
"aobao:target:tatamotors:tatar:tattoo:tax:taxi:tc:tci:td:tdk:team:tech:technology"+
":tel:telecity:telefonica:temasek:tennis:teva:tf:tg:th:thd:theater:theatre:tiaa:t"+
"ickets:tienda:tiffany:tips:tires:tirol:tj:tjmaxx:tjx:tk:tkmaxx:tl:tm:tmall:tn:to"+
":today:tokyo:tools:top:toray:toshiba:total:tours:town:toyota:toys:tp:tr:trade:tr"+
"ading:training:travel:travelchannel:travelers:travelersinsurance:trust:trv:tt:tu"+
"be:tui:tunes:tushu:tv:tvs:tw:tz:ua:ubank:ubs:uconnect:ug:uk:um:unicom:university"+
":uno:uol:ups:us:uy:uz:va:vacations:vana:vanguard:vc:ve:vegas:ventures:verisign:v"+
"ersicherung:vet:vg:vi:viajes:video:vig:viking:villas:vin:vip:virgin:visa:vision:"+
"vista:vistaprint:viva:vivo:vlaanderen:vn:vodka:volkswagen:volvo:vote:voting:voto"+
":voyage:vu:vuelos:wales:walmart:walter:wang:wanggou:warman:watch:watches:weather"+
":weatherchannel:webcam:weber:website:wed:wedding:weibo:weir:wf:whoswho:wien:wiki"+
":williamhill:win:windows:wine:winners:wme:wolterskluwer:woodside:work:works:worl"+
"d:wow:ws:wtc:wtf:xbox:xerox:xfinity:xihuan:xin:测试:कॉम:परीक्षा:セール:佛山:ಭಾರತ:慈善:集团:"+
"在线:한국:ଭାରତ:大众汽车:点看:คอม:ভাৰত:ভারত:八卦:.موقع‎:বাংলা:公益:公司:香格里拉:网站:移动:我爱你:москва:исп"+
"ытание:қаз:католик:онлайн:сайт:联通:срб:бг:бел:.קום‎:时尚:微博:테스트:淡马锡:ファッション:орг:नेट:"+
"ストア:삼성:சிங்கப்பூர்:商标:商店:商城:дети:мкд:.טעסט‎:ею:ポイント:新闻:工行:家電:.كوم‎:中文网:中信:中国:中國:"+
"娱乐:谷歌:భారత్:ලංකා:電訊盈科:购物:測試:クラウド:ભારત:通販:भारतम्:भारत:भारोत:.آزمایشی‎:பரிட்சை:网店:"+
"संगठन:餐厅:网络:ком:укр:香港:诺基亚:食品:δοκιμή:飞利浦:.إختبار‎:台湾:台灣:手表:手机:мон:.الجزائر‎:.عما"+
"ن‎:.ارامكو‎:.ایران‎:.العليان‎:.اتصالات‎:.امارات‎:.بازار‎:.پاکستان‎:.الاردن‎:.موب"+
"ايلي‎:.بارت‎:.بھارت‎:.المغرب‎:.ابوظبي‎:.السعودية‎:.ڀارت‎:.كاثوليك‎:.سودان‎:.همرا"+
"ه‎:.عراق‎:.مليسيا‎:澳門:닷컴:政府:.شبكة‎:.بيتك‎:.عرب‎:გე:机构:组织机构:健康:ไทย:.سورية‎:рус:рф"+
":珠宝:.تونس‎:大拿:みんな:グーグル:ελ:世界:書籍:ഭാരതം:ਭਾਰਤ:网址:닷넷:コム:天主教:游戏:vermögensberater:verm"+
"ögensberatung:企业:信息:嘉里大酒店:嘉里:.مصر‎:.قطر‎:广东:இலங்கை:இந்தியா:հայ:新加坡:.فلسطين‎:テスト:"+
"政务:xperia:xxx:xyz:yachts:yahoo:yamaxun:yandex:ye:yodobashi:yoga:yokohama:you:you"+
"tube:yt:yun:za:zappos:zara:zero:zip:zippo:zm:zone:zuerich:zw";

const tld = new Set(tlddata.split(":"));

function urlInfo(url) {
  const split = url.split(".");
  const split1 = split[0].split("@");
  let p = split.length - 1;
  if (split1.length === 2) split[0] = split1[1];  
  while (tld.has(split[p])) p --;
  return {
    domain: split[p],
    subdomain: split.slice(0, p).join("."),
    tld: split.slice(p + 1).join(".")
  };
}

const test = [
  "test@domain.com",
  "test@domain.co.uk",
  "test@subdomain.domain.com",
  "test@subdomain.domain.co.uk",
  "test@subdomain.domain.com.au",
  "test@subdomain.domain.me"
  ];
  
test.forEach((url) => {
  const info = urlInfo(url);
  console.log(`${url}  D=${info.domain}  S=${info.subdomain ? info.subdomain : "None"}  TLD:${info.tld}`);
});
```

Comment: Wow, amazing! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
    else
     {
       if(isSubdomain(x)) 
         alert("You entered a valid e-mail address with sub domain.");
     }
}

 function isSubdomain(url) {

    var regex = new RegExp(/([\w-]+\.[\w-]+\.\w+)$/);

     return url.match(regex); // make sure it returns boolean
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page_post.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, but email like: test@domain.co.uk is treated as a subdomain.

Answer (score -2):

You can use  the following script for this type of email validation.

```js
var filter = /^\w+(?:\.\w+)*@\w+(?:\.\w+)+$/;
```

Comment: I tried with your regex, and it always returned false. I have added the function in the question.